# Finding the transition probability of a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Suppose that the probability it rains today is 0.3 if neither of the last two days was rainy, but 0.6 if at least one of the last two days was rainy. Let the weather on day $n$, $W_n$, be $R$ for rain, or $S$ for sun. $W_n$ is not a Markov chain, but the weather for the last two days $X_n$ = $(W_{n-1}, W_n)$ is a Markov chain with four states {$RR$, $RS$, $SR$, $SS$}. (a) Compute its transition probability. (b) Compute the two-step transition probability. (c) What is the probability it will rain on Wednesday given that it did not rain on Sunday or Monday?

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not sure how the weather for the last two days, $X_n$, can possibly be a Markov chain. For example, with $X_n$ = $(W_{n-1}, W_n)$, wouldn't the probability of $W_n$ being rainy depend on $W_{n-1}$ and $W_{n-2}$? Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not claim $W_n$ **is** a Markov chain, on the contrary. So you actually need to check if $P(X_n | X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}, \ldots, X_{\text{initial}}) = P(X_n | X_{n-1})$. If it is for all states - it is a Markov chain. You have 4 states, so it even could be made by hand.

Comment: Upon looking at the problem again I'm seeing where my thinking was going wrong - thank you!